# Display man page from stdin

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, manpage

I am developing a man page using rst. While I am doing that, I would like a quick way of displaying my end result. I currently do it like this:

```
rst2man < the-man-page.rst > tmp
man ./tmp
```

Is there a way to do this with a one liner without creating a temporary file? I have tried to pipe the output directly to the man command.

Comment: Good question. None of the standard tricks seem to work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `--local-file` argument of the man command and specify `-` to read from stdin.

**Example:**

```
rst2man < the-man-page.rst | man -l -
```

Comment: Seems like `--local-file` is only implemented in **man-db** http://www.nongnu.org/man-db/

Comment: I am using Fedora 20 with man version 2.6.5. It works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: how to use on MacOS?