# How do I view Markdown file like a man page without making a temporary file?

Tags: bash, macos, markdown, pandoc, manpage

I'd like to read Markdown files like `man` pages. I can do this:

```
pandoc README.md -t man --standalone > tmp_file && man ./tmp_file
```

However, I'd like to do this without creating a temporary file. I tried:

```
man <(pandoc README.md -t man –standalone)
```

But I got an error:

```
fgets: Undefined error: 0
Error reading man page /dev/fd/63
No manual entry for /dev/fd/63
```

Any ideas? I *did* look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802024/display-man-page-from-stdin), but that doesn't work on macOS's version of `man`, it seems.

I really don't care about using `man`, *per se*, but I'd like to be able to view prettily-formatted Markdown files in the terminal. `pandoc` can convert to groff, which I can then send to `man` to get the nice display. Is there a program that `man` uses under the hood that might work?

Comment: Does `nroff -man` work for you on the output from `pandoc -t man`? Seems to me that `nroff -man <(pandoc -t man -standalone filename)` should be fine.

Comment: With Linux: `pandoc README.md -t man --standalone | man /dev/stdin`?

Comment: @ghoti That seems to work too!

Comment: @Cyrus The `/dev/stdin` special device might be implemented differently on Linux. It doesn't seem to work on macOS. That'd be a neat hack, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this pipe to groff:

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -t man README.md | groff -T utf8 -man | less
```

([Source](http://blog.metamatt.com/blog/2013/01/09/previewing-markdown-files-from-the-terminal/))

Comment: Also this works fine : `man -l <(pandoc -s -f markdown -t man readme.md)`

Answer (score 1):

I use this shell function:

```
mdv () { # This function display Markdown in the terminal from file or "-"
  pandoc -s -t man ${1:-"-"} | # Read into Pandoc from file or STDIN
  groff -T utf8 -man         | # format for Pager
  sed 1,4d | head -n -4      | # Chop off 4 leading/trailing (empty) lines
  ${PAGER:-$(DN=/dev/null;     # Use $PAGER, if available
             which less &>$DN && { echo "less -FRSEX"; } || # less w/ opts
               which more 2>$DN || echo cat                )} # Fallbacks
}
```

The basic idea is the same as in the accepted answer, I just have added a few bells and whistles around it, and wrapped it in a documented function