# Disable pandoc conversion of double quotes when outputting plain text

Tags: markdown, pandoc, double-quotes

Here is the markdown file `test.md`:

```
# Introduction
He said, "Hello!".
```

I want to convert this to text using pandoc suitable for displaying on the command-line. To do this I run `pandoc -t plain test.md` which results in

```
INTRODUCTION


He said, â€œHello!â€.
```

What I *want* is for the double-quotes to be left as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn off [smart quotes](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-smart) use:

```
pandoc -f markdown-smart -t plain test.md
```

To display it in a terminal you might try [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51544899/214446):

```
pandoc -s -f markdown-smart -t man test.md | groff -T utf8 -man | less
```