# Show MAN formatted file or variable from STDIN in Linux/Darwin / NOT with RST/POD

Tags: bash, shell, formatting, stdin, manpage

I have a script with some 'USAGE' function. It echoes the params/args, etc. I know I can create a custom MAN page file, as of ex:

```
.TH man 8 "09 May 2021" "1.0" "myscript man page"
.SH NAME
myscript \- do some stuff
.SH SYNOPSIS
myscript [STUFF]
.SH DESCRIPTION
myscript is very useful and blah blah blah lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lazy dog jump over the brown fox.
```

and read it just fine, so it will be shown as a man page with

```
man ./man-file
```

Anyways, I want to embed this into the script; then show it as MAN formatted from there. I dont want to have an external file for it.

Simple part, is simple. Create a var within the script having above contents as MAN syntax. Now, how can I show it as MAN formatted?

Here are my tryings, nothing yielded any good result.

```
echo $man_text_var | man
```

```
man < <(echo $man_text_var)
```

```
echo $man_text_var | man /dev/stdin
```

```
man /dev/stdin <<EOF
   $man_text_var
EOF
```

is there a way to accomplish it? and yes, I did see the post [Display man page from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802024/display-man-page-from-stdin) - but it does not solve my problem. not using RST or POD.

Comment: So did you see that `| man -l -` in the duplicate? What do you think it does? Please do not delete questions and recreate them exactly the same... As said, for starters change `echo $man_text_var` to `echo "$man_text_va"` - it's one of the errors shellcheck.net will tell you about. Then pipe it to `man -l -`, as explained _in the duplicate_ `You can use the --local-file argument of the man command and specify - to read from stdin`, please _read_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802024/display-man-page-from-stdin .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it with `groff` which is available on every distro.

```
echo "${x}" | groff -man -Tascii | less
```